# Juice UI save sortable data

Tags: asp.net, juice-ui

I am using JQuery UI port to ASP.NET Webforms called JuiceUI.

Problem:

I have an unordered list `ul` and a few list elements `li`. I also have the `<juice:sortable>` that works pretty well in client side.

Now, after sorting it, I might want to save the sorted list into a database. I've searched hard and long on the internet to do just that and to no avail.

Is there *any* way to save the sorted unordered list into the table? In other words, can we "get" the sequence of the unordered list into the backend C# code?

Here is what I have until now:

```
 <ul id="_Default" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="list-style-type:none;height:5%">
        <li class="ui-state-default" style="float:left; margin-left:10px"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item-1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" style="float:left; margin-left:10px"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item-2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" style="float:left; margin-left:10px"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item-3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" style="float:left; margin-left:10px"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item-4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" style="float:left; margin-left:10px"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item-5</li>
   </ul>
   <juice:sortable ID="Sortable1" TargetControlID="_Default" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="True" onreceive="Sortable1_Receive" onstop="Sortable1_Stop" 
        Tolerance="pointer"/>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbP" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Freeze" />
```

And the `Button1_Click` event code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _Default.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Web.UI.LiteralControl cntl = (System.Web.UI.LiteralControl)_Default.Controls[i];
                tbP.Text += cntl.Text + " ";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

(I no longer maintain Juice UI, but I've struggled with this implementation on my fork, [Brew](http://shellscape.org/#brew))

The problem you have is *which* data to send back to the server. You can check to see if the targeted control for sorting has data bound to it, and through some inspection can figure out which fields are databound and send that back, but what if it's just a list of elements? I could restrict the code to a particular data source (text, html, attribute, databinding, etc) or try to cover the entire gauntlet of possibilities - but that get's messy.

I'm up for suggestions.

Comment: why not a model similar to ReorderList from ASP.net AjaxControlToolkit? Where, each reorder of elements can trigger a postback and we can capture the element sequence from there.

Comment: it could just send back the sequence `HtmlLiteralControls` from the `ul` element. Because finally they are a bunch of `li`s.

Comment: that's not really an elegant way to implement that feature. just because it's in the ACT doesn't make it a good method. one of the motivations behind juice ui and Brew was that the ACT is pretty awful, but I digress.